# Feature org.graalvm.home.HomeFinderFeature class not found

Tags: javafx, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I downloaded the Java/JavaFX source from [RubikFX](https://github.com/chirontt/RubikFX).

I installed GraalVM Java21 from Oracle's [site](https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/) for a Linux Mint 21, amd64 laptop.

In the pom.xml I upped the version of the GluonFX plugin from 1.0.18 to 1.0.21 since using J21.

After setting JAVA_HOME, PATH and GRAALVM_HOME I ran:

mvn javafx:run

and got an error in the log that stating: "launcher.c:28:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory"

After a bit of googling, the suggestion was to run:

sudo apt-get install libc6-dev

I then re-ran:

mvn javafx:run

and this time got:

```
Error: Feature org.graalvm.home.HomeFinderFeature class not found on the classpath. Ensure that the name is correct and that the class is on the classpath.
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Feature org.graalvm.home.HomeFinderFeature class not found on the classpath. Ensure that the name is correct and that the class is on the classpath.
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:73)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.registerFeatures(FeatureHandler.java:183)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:896)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:590)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:550)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:538)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:720)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.start(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:142)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:97)
```

Has anyone else seen this, and know of a solution?

BTW - I am not particularly interested in this specific Java/JavaFX but picked it because I saw the developer had added the JavaFX/GluonFX GraalVM plugins and assumed he'd got things to work, and so wanted to replicate his build. Over the past year or so I've tried numerous times to get the simplest of HelloWorld JavaFX apps to build in  GraalVM and never had any success yet. And that luck seems to continue.

Comment: If you are using the GluonFX plugin, it is recommended to use the Gluon's build of GraalVM: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_linux. Newer official GraalVM versions have changes that might not be supported.

Comment: The link you provided is for Java11 and Java17. As stated in the post, I'm using Java21. I have previously tried both Java11 and Java17 with JavaFX and not had any luck. I've posted this here on Stcackoverflow and also on a GraalVM website forum, and others have seen the same issues. Thus, I wanted to try the latest release.